# pvporcupine error = porcupine=pvporcupine.create(keywords=["jarvis","alexa"]) TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'access_key'

Tags: python

This code for a hotword for jarvis has an error:

```
import struct
import pyaudio
import pvporcupine
porcupine=None
paud=None
audio_stream=None

try:
    porcupine=pvporcupine.create(keywords=["jarvis","alexa"]) #pvporcupine.KEYWORDS for all keywords
    paud=pyaudio.PyAudio()
    audio_stream=paud.open(rate=porcupine.sample_rate,channels=1,format=pyaudio.paInt16,input=True,frames_per_buffer=porcupine.frame_length)
    while True:
        keyword=audio_stream.read(porcupine.frame_length)
        keyword=struct.unpack_from("h"*porcupine.frame_length,keyword)
        keyword_index=porcupine.process(keyword)
        if keyword_index>=0:
            print("hotword detected")
                
    
finally:
    if porcupine is not None:
        porcupine.delete()
    if audio_stream is not None:
        audio_stream.close()
    if paud is not None:
        paud.terminate()
```

Here's the error I get:

```
porcupine=pvporcupine.create(keywords=["jarvis","alexa"]) #pvporcupine.KEYWORDS for all keywords
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'access_key'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation here https://pypi.org/project/pvporcupine/ , will see that you need obtain a access_key and  initialize the object like this:

```
access_key = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY}"  # AccessKey obtained from Picovoice Console (https://picovoice.ai/console/)
porcupine=pvporcupine.create(access_key=access_key, keywords=["jarvis","alexa"])
```